# Group DataFrame by period of time with aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, aggregation

I am using Pandas to structure and process Data. This is my DataFrame:

[image]

I grouped many datetimes by minute and I did an aggregation in order to have the sum of 'bitrate' scores by minute.
This was my code to have this Dataframe:

```
def aggregate_data(data):

    def delete_seconds(time):

        return (datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).replace(second=0)


    data['new_time'] = data['beginning_time'].apply(delete_seconds)
    df = (data[['new_time', 'bitrate']].groupby(['new_time'])).aggregate(np.sum)

    return df
```

Now I want to do a similar thing with 5 minutes as buckets. I wand to do group my datetimes by 5 minutes and do a mean.. 
Something like this : (This dosent work of course!)

```
df.groupby([df.index.map(lambda t: t.5minute)]).aggregate(np.mean)
```

Ideas ? Thx !

Comment: if your index is already a datetimeIndex then you can just use `resample`: `df.resample('5min').mean()` should work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling).

`df.resample('5Min').sum()`

This assumes your index is properly set as a DateTimeIndex.

you can also use the TimeGrouper, as resampling is a groupby operation on time buckets.

`df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5Min')).sum()`

Comment: Can u help me to do this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691671/resampling-timeseries-with-a-given-timedelta